# What are the advantages of a preinstalled Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: 14.04

I have used ubuntu on a dell inspiron n5010 for 2 months.

I loved how everything was well integrated but it had a video driver problem which caused the display to flash at boot (basically it looked ugly). Then one day after I plugged in my external drive everything stopped working, the external drive failed to mount and when I restarted the computer, it failed to boot.

It wont even reinstall the os from live usb. Then I sent it for repair, got it back after 1 week with Windows 7 installed. Windows even managed to managed to "scan and fix" my 1 TB external drive after churning away at it for 8hrs. So after this huge mess I am a bit apprehensive to try ubuntu again.

I want to buy an ubuntu preinstalled laptop to save some money so I need to know if ubuntu is stable or not. Maybe I had done something wrong last time or maybe my laptop just wasn't made for Linux. I would love to know your valued opinion. I have always used Windows before trying Linux and am currently running Windows 10

Comment: We are not a hardware related site so most of this(if not all) will be off topic. But 2 things: a notebook with Ubuntu pre-installed will have all the stable drivers you need and have it configured. And 2: you could always go back to Windows if needed (as long as you have a valid Windows installation medium and use that for just 1 system).

Comment: Well, Dell seems to be selling laptops with Ubuntu in India so let us know how you get on :) http://www.compuindia.com/ is favored by Dell but other e-tailers carry Ubuntu-loaded Dell laptops as well.

Comment: Hmm Ubuntu is stable (go for 14.04 version over 15.10). I'd suggest you do use it - it's good. But buying it preinstalled isn't likely so save any money tbh.

Comment: Thank you. What should i avoid doing to keep ubuntu as stable as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to buy a preinstalled GNU/Linux pc before (more than 10 years!)

To get a computer the most free as in freedom possible hardware made, it's necessary. So you'll have to know well the insides. (for me, basically graphics and wireless adapters are important) The worst is normally there is basic information that shops don't give us. (energy consumption, wireless chipset...)

If you get this info simply 'duckduckgo' it (or 'google' it if you prefer) to see how people complain about, etc.

h-node.org is a web page basic to know compatibility hardware with absolutely free drivers.
Linux foundation has some stuff too.

Intel is who gives best support to free as in freedom drivers in graphics video adapters.

And also, buy GNU/Linux PCs is a very good option. (or at least, without os)
Of course. (and support GNU/Linux related industry is a good point, of course)